# Django: Check if an instance exists before creating

Tags: django, api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have two models `Purchaser` and `paymentInvoice`, I want to make sure i don't create a duplicate `Purchaser` object when i'm creating a new `paymentInvoice` for the same `Purchaser` individual/instance.

Basically i have a `Purchaser` by the name *Becky*, so when i want to create an invoice for *Becky* 1st i want to make sure if the name *Becky* exists in `Purchaser` if it does, create `paymentInvoice` object with *Becky* taking the field `invoiceOwner`. If *Becky* doesn't exist in `Purchaser`, create an instance of that purchaser in `Purchaser` then use that instance name to create `paymentInvoice` object.

**Models** file

```
class Purchaser(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.png', upload_to='customer_photos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    data_added = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class paymentInvoice(models.Model):

    invoiceNo = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, default=increment_invoice_number)
    invoiceOwner = models.ForeignKey(Purchaser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="invoice_detail")
    product = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    date = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    quantity = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True, default=1)
    payment_made = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.invoiceOwner.name
```

**Serializers** file

```
class paymentInvoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    invoiceOwner = purchaserSerializer(many=False)
    invoiceOwner = serializers.CharField(source='invoiceOwner.name')

    class Meta:
        model = paymentInvoice
        fields = '__all__'

    def create(self, validated_data):
        purchaser_data = validated_data.pop("invoiceOwner")

        purchaser, _ = Purchaser.objects.get_or_create(**purchaser_data).first()
        validated_data.update({"invoiceOwner": purchaser})

        return paymentInvoice.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

**Views** file

```
class PurchaserListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = purchaserSerializer
    queryset = Purchaser.objects.all()

class paymentInvoiceListCreateView(ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = paymentInvoiceSerializer
    queryset = paymentInvoice.objects.all().order_by('-date')
```

**POST** request in Postman for the model `paymentInvoice`

```
{
    "invoiceOwner":"Becky",
    "product": "Lix",
    "quantity": 1,
    "payment_made": 3000
}
```

My way is not working, i get the error from PostMan

> MultipleObjectsReturned at /api/clients/invoice/
> get() returned more than one Purchaser -- it returned 2!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first check for the record if not found then create one like below

```py
    def create(self, validated_data):
        purchaser_data = validated_data.pop("invoiceOwner")

        purchaser = Purchaser.objects.filter(**purchaser_data).first()
        if purchaser is None:
             purchaser = Purchaser.objects.create(**purchaser_data)
        validated_data.update({"invoiceOwner": purchaser})

        return paymentInvoice.objects.create(**validated_data)
```

Comment: It is better to use **`.exists()`** than `.first()`

Comment: @ArakkalAbu no, he need the object as well `.exists` returns a boolean so it won't work

Answer (score 0):

Probably get_or_create should work also, just i think you should redifine get_or_create not create method .

```
  def get_or_create(self):
   purchaser_data = validated_data.pop("invoiceOwner")
   purchase,created = Purchase.objects.get_or_create(**purchaser_data)
   validated_data.update({"invoiceOwner": purchaser})
   payment_invoice = paymentInvoice.objects.create(**validated_data)
   return payment_invoice,created
```

in view :

```
model_serializer = paymentInvoiceSerializer(data=request.data)
if model_serializer.is_valid():
   payment_invoice,_ = model_serializer.get_or_create()
```

Comment: Can you perform the implementation using **get_or_create** i'm curious since mine did not work

Comment: can you share the wiew please

Comment: `get_or_create` will through MultipleObjectsReturned error because there are multiple Purchaser data for that query

Comment: yes yes you arwhit the problem you should redfine the get_or_create method not cretae, i would ask you where in view you use the create methode